# PowerShell script to configure Windows service with no password user

Tags: powershell

I would like to configure a service (adding log in user and set the start up to automatic) and start it using a Powershell script:

`Set-Service -Name [ServiceName] -StartupType Automatic
$LocalSrv = Get-WmiObject Win32_service -filter "name='[Servicename]'"
$LocalSrv.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$false,$env:computername+"\"+$env:UserName, "")
Start-Service -Name [Servicename]`

the issue is that when the logged in user doesn't have a password i tried ("", '',  $null) in last param of $LocalSrv.Change() and nothing worked.

You help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bit easier - use WMI.

```
$service = gwmi win32_service -computer [computername] -filter "name='whatever'"
$service.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"P@ssw0rd")
```

Change the service name appropriately in the filter; set the remote computer name appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,

I am getting the following error using your script: 
Start-Service : Service 'xxx (xxx)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot
start service xxx on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:2
+  Start-Service -Name TruckmasterManager
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

Comment: what is your powershell version ?

Comment: Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17763  771